# Force Calculate A Duration To Year

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I've a requirement where I've to force a duration to show as two years completion. As as example, any of the customers who are active online in an app from 2016 to 2018, should be considered as two years completion in the app. This seems straight-forward and used the following `Linq` to make it work:

```
var result = (from c in db.Users
              where c.UserId == id && (c.Start.Year >= 2016 && c.End.Year <= 2018)
              select c).ToList ();

 int years = 0;
 if (result.Count () > 0)
 {
     years = 2;
 }
 else
 {
    //Logic goes here
 }
```

So it can be seen that I am forcing it to calculate the two years duration. Depending upon this, I would grant the users a 20% loyalty in the system. Though I've bit complexity to build the logic. Again, in the range, a user may be active between 2016 and 2017. So these users will not be eligible for the loyalty.

How can I make the above work for two conditions for two years as well for the users that aren't eligible? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to have a Start Year of 2015 and End Year 2019?  Do they also get your loyalty %?

Comment: The `Linq` seems promising @Tim Schmelter. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Yes @Tyddlywink. That comes in the conditon as it's between 2015 and 2017 - Two years.

Comment: Then you want this `(c.Start.Year <= 2016 && c.End.Year >= 2018)`  but this will only return user with a start year 2016 or less and end yesr 2018 or greater.  You will never get a user with less than 2 years.  Didn't seem like that's what you are after.

Comment: Yes and I can retrieve that. But I want the second one as well like the users less than two years @Tyddlywink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.   It gets the user and determines the timespan between start year and end year assigns that value to years and then checks if it's less than 2. If so do your logic.  I'm making the assumption that UserId is unique and there will always be at least one entry.

Here is a working Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bVDpkF

```
var result = (
    from c in db.Users
    where c.UserId == id
    select c).Single();



int years =  result.End.Year - result.Start.Year;

if (years <= 2)
{
//Logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Good one @Tyddlywink. I'll try that as well and was thinking on this.

Comment: Added a Fiddle to show it working.  I guessed at your User class structure.  And in my example above I oops and flipped the math.  End should subtract Start.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tyddlywink and worked perfectly. Though I am curious about one thing and if you could provide a solution. Say I am calculating with year (2016 To 2018 - Two years) right now. Now if I want to force month as well with years, say (Jan, 2006 To Dec, 2008 - Two years), how will the logic be implemented?

Comment: And July 2006 to April 2008 is not 2 years?

Comment: I'm going to assume yes to my previous question.  This will do it for you.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/bVDpkF

Comment: Thanks for the logic @Tyddlywink but could you specify this - **var EndDate = result.End.AddDays((result.End.Day-1)*-1); var StartDate = result.Start.AddDays((result.Start.Day-1)*-1); TimeSpan span = EndDate - StartDate;**?? Is it possible to do this - 12/1/2016 - 1/1/2014 = 2? And yes, this is correct - **And July 2006 to April 2008 is not 2 years?**. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Sure.  But you asked for Month.  Here it is using the full End and Start dates in the calculations.   https://dotnetfiddle.net/bVDpkF

Comment: Thanks again @Tyddlywink. But this should be the condition: 12/1/2016 - 1/1/2014 = 2 and 11/1/2016 - 1/1/2014 != 2.

Comment: Guess you are going to have to explain why a Start Date of 1/1/2014 and an End Date of 12/1/2016 is 2 years but a Start Date of 1/1/2014 and an End Date of 11/1/2016 is not.  They are both more than 2 years whose only difference is a month.   https://dotnetfiddle.net/bVDpkF# now iterates over the entire list spitting out the results for each User.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe calculate the timespan in the Linq query.

```
var list = cItems.Where(x => ((TimeSpan)(x.End - x.Start)).Days > 730).ToList();
```

Comment: This will work for one condition, I guess. I require to check if the users are active more than or equal to two years as well less than two. I commented on the answer of @Tyddlywink and would be better if you could provide a solution for that. Thanks a lot.